# What is the significance of the _sm_nck=1 querystring?

Tags: http

What is the significance of the querystring:

> _sm_nck=1

that I see appended to a lot of page requests?  What adds it and why?

We are seeing the occasional page request coming into our site with that parameter added, usually as a second request for the same page from the same IP address a few seconds later.  Also if I 'Google' that parameter I see a high number of search results have it appended too.

Comment: In what context? Do you have an example?

Comment: I found it as well in my access logs, probably some random software or browser addon doing tests on remote files.

Answer (score 5):

I think it has something to do with ZScaler not having the site in its database of sites. See the image below. I did not add the `_sm_nck` myself.

[image: zscaler error message]